# Nested list in iOS Notes

Tags: ios, notes.app

I might be missing something obvious, but I can't figure out how to create a nested list in iOS Notes. It's easy on a Mac (just use the tab key), and the iPhone renders a nested list fine, but there doesn't seem to be any way to indent a bullet to the second level of nesting while composing on iOS. Any way to do this?

[image: Nested list in Notes for iPhone]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent versions of iOS, there's a faster, more direct way of manipulating indentation: you can swipe a given line, to the right or to the left, to respectively indent it or de-indent it.

Comment: Confirmed, works in iOS 14.

Answer (score 5):

1. Tap "Aa" symbol

   [image]
2. Then tap this symbol (It acts an a Tab-right)

[image]

Comment: Ugh... facepalm.

Comment: @duozmo Don't worry about it. Contributes to the site and helps others. :)